# NoMethodError, calling attribute in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, nomethoderror

I have a sinatra app that I am writing. I am trying to write a page to display the individual patterns stored in a database. Using datamapper I have created a class:

```
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'

DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")

class Pattern
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :patt, String
    property :sentence, String
    property :descript, Text
end

DataMapper.finalize
```

The route to handle the /pattern/:id is...

```
get '/pattern/:id' do
    @patts = Pattern.get(params[:id])
    erb :pattern
end
```

And in my pattern.erb file...

```
<div class="span10">
    <h2><%= @patts.patt %></h2>
    <p>Example: <%= @patts.sentence % @patts.patt %><p>
    <p>Description: <%= @patts.descript %></p>
</div>
```

The error I get is...

```
NoMethodError at /pattern/1
undefined method `patt' for nil:NilClass
file: pattern.erb location: block in singleton class line: 6
```

What is it that I am not doing or doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, `@patts = Pattern.get(params[:id])` is giving you `nil`
Most likely, the `id` you passed doesn't match an existing pattern id (because there either are no patterns, or you're hitting the url wrong). Whatever the reason, you're going to need to handle that with something along the lines of:

```
if @patt
  # Your code
else
  'No pattern by that id' # or something similar.
end
```

either in your controller or your .erb.

Comment: That'll definitely be a good idea to implement. But, I know that I am calling a correct ID. The URL is being generated by using the variable for the ID of the pattern. Essentially "/pattern/#{pattern.id}", aside from that, I have manually entered the URL with known pattern IDs and they all come back the same.

Comment: @DavidKarasek Are you getting values for `@patts`? Something is wrong such that your @patts is nil. If you put `p Pattern.all` above the offending line, does it log your patterns? This bug is really weird if indeed you are passing a valid id (which it looks like) to a database with valid entries (which _could_ be the issue, but shouldn't be likely).

Answer (score -1):

this may because your table is empty. Try insert a record into your table first.

You should add some test codes like this:

```
'/pattern/:id' do 

  puts params[:id] 

  @patts = Pattern.get(params[:id]) 

  puts @patts 

  erb :pattern 

end
```

Comment: It isn't. I have data in it, that is displayed on other sections of the app without problem.

Comment: You should add some test codes like this:        ```'/pattern/:id' do    puts  params[:id]            
    @patts = Pattern.get(params[:id]) puts @patts
    erb :pattern
end```